# Using a BETWEEN in ON Clause of LEFT JOIN doesn't use any index

Tags: mysql, indexing, left-join, between

I am selecting `cells` by `shop_id` and additionally i want to know how many `takes` are within the defined area of a `cell`. Those are wgs84-coordinates, but because im not overlapping the greenwith prime meridian, i dont have to care for that. So i tried simply using two BETWEEN-Statements in the on clause.

As long as i am using an INNER JOIN, it works perfectly fine. But i also needed those cells that dont have any takes, so i later switched to LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT `cell`.*, COUNT(take.take_id)
FROM `cell`
LEFT JOIN `take` ON 
    (take.take_lat BETWEEN cell.cell_lat_south AND cell.cell_lat_north) AND
    (take.take_lon BETWEEN cell.cell_lon_west AND cell.cell_lon_east)
WHERE (cell.shop_id = '1')
GROUP BY `cell`.`cell_id`
```

I am getting the expected results, but instead of under 1 second (as with INNER JOIN), it takes over 1 minute to execute. And thats with only ~3000 cells involved.

EXPLAINing the SELECT query results in no use of any indexes i put on all the coordinate-columns:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+----------------------------------------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys                                | key     | key_len | ref   | rows   | filtered | Extra                                          |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+----------------------------------------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cell  | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,shop_id,cell_lat_south,cell_lon_west | shop_id | 4       | const |   2936 |   100.00 | Using index condition                          |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | take  | NULL       | ALL  | take_lat                                     | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  | 136822 |   100.00 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x4) |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+----------------------------------------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
```

In the end i tried a query where the JOIN is replaced with a SUBQUERY:

```
SELECT `cell`.*, (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM `take`
    WHERE
        take.take_lat BETWEEN cell.cell_lat_south AND cell.cell_lat_north AND
        take.take_lon BETWEEN cell.cell_lon_west AND cell.cell_lon_east)
    as `take_count`
FROM `cell`
WHERE (cell.shop_id = '1')
```

This yields the correct results and the query is fast again. But the odd thing is within the explain, which now shows `filtered` at `1.23` instead of `100` before. Still no index used:

```
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows   | filtered | Extra                                          |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | cell  | NULL       | ref  | shop_id       | shop_id | 4       | const |   2936 |   100.00 | NULL                                           |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | take  | NULL       | ALL  | take_lat      | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  | 136822 |     1.23 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x4) |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
```

The tables look like this:

`cell` with ~450k rows

```
cell_id | shop_id | cell_lat_north | cell_lat_south | cell_lon_west | cell_lon_east
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       | 1       | 54.858601      | 54.849621      | 14.074777     | 14.089339    
2       | 1       | 54.858601      | 54.849621      | 14.089339     | 14.103901    
3       | 2       | 54.858601      | 54.849621      | 14.103901     | 14.118464
```

```
CREATE TABLE cell (
    cell_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    shop_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    cell_lat_north float(10,6) NOT NULL,
    cell_lat_south float(10,6) NOT NULL,
    cell_lon_west float(10,6) NOT NULL,
    cell_lon_east float(10,6) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (cell_id),
    KEY shop_id (shop_id),
    KEY cell_lat_south (cell_lat_south,cell_lat_north),
    KEY cell_lon_west (cell_lon_west,cell_lon_east)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

`take` with ~130k rows

```
take_id | take_lat       | take_lon
------------------------------------
1       | 54.851234      | 14.081234
2       | 54.851234      | 14.081234
```

```
CREATE TABLE take (
     take_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     take_lat float(10,6) NOT NULL,
     take_lon float(10,6) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (take_id),
     KEY shop_id (shop_id),
     KEY take_lat (take_lat,take_lon)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: I can't see the explain

Comment: Which columns have index? And can you add inner join query that runs faster?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`

Comment: On `take`:  `INDEX(take_lat, take_lon)`.